# Opening SQL with Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, xcode, sqlite

I have an sql file in my supporting files.  How can I open this file so that I can start using SQL commands to get the information that I want?  I've tried a couple different syntaxes, and the last time I tried I ended up screwing up the whole application because I couldn't remember what I had changed.

Comment: are you using sqlite 3 ?

Comment: As a side note, the CoreData framework is much better than direct access if this database is only used by your program or app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sqlite 3. Then,

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject];
NSString* dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
{
     NSLog(@"Opened Database");
    //Your code
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
     sqlite3_close (database);
}
```

Comment: The only problem I'm having with this is it's telling me database is undefined.  I get that it's there to communicate with the database, but where is database defined/declared?  This might be a dumb question.  I haven't dealt with databases in Objective-c before.

Comment: Please define database in your .h file as, sqlite3 *dataBase; Also include the header file sqlite3.h. And framework of sqlite3.0